# UIImageView: Strange tintColor behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, storyboard, tintcolor

I have an UIViewController with an UIImageView which shows an image with rendering mode Always Template (set via assets catalog). The image view has a tintColor set in storyboard. When I start the app, the image is still white and not colored correctly.

So I tried it programmatically with the following code...

```
self.infoImageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 155.0 / 255.0, blue: 165.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

It worked! Next I want do not want to use the UIColor constructor with the rgba values, I want to use the color of the asset catalog. So I drag and dropped the color from the Media Library in the code...

```
self.infoImageView.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.6078431373, blue: 0.6470588235, alpha: 1)
```

... and it didn't work! So I thought iOS has a problem with the color or the name of the color in the asset catalog. I renamed it and drag and dropped the color again...

```
self.infoImageView.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.6079999804, blue: 0.6470000148, alpha: 1)
```

and it worked! The strange thing is, that the rgb values had changed by just renaming the color.

Has someone an idea why the tintColor in Storyboard didn't work? Or why the first color from the Media Library doesn't work, too? Or why the rgb values had changed? I'm very confused at the moment...

Comment: Xcode version? was it using simulator or real device? iOS version?

Comment: Xcode 9.2, iOS 11.2, on simulator and real device @kd02

Comment: I struggled to replicate your issue, the tint color worked for me using storyboard, code behind using UIColor and #colorLiteral so there must be something else affecting your imageview. As for the change in rgb values - I really can't explain that